# How to include a (compiled) JS file in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I’ve a NuxtJS app and want to include a file called `app.js` (located in `assets/js/app.js`).

Contents of that file:

```
// imports from node_modules
import 'focus-visible';
import 'other-package';
…
```

What I am doing at the moment is to `import` that packages inside `layouts/default.vue` … but it doesn’t feel right.

How would you do it?

Comment: For global, use a plugin, the above code would go in plugins dir, then you use nuxt.conf.js to load it, putting it in layout is fine if its layout specific, though each to own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing the `assets` file is no different than importing any other JavaScript file from another `src` directory:

```js
import '@/assets/js/app'
```

It's hard to say whether this usage is "right" without more context, but I don't see anything wrong with doing that.